# How to get access intermediate layers parameters in BERT pretrained models?

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

```
import torch
import transformers
tokenizer = transformers.AlbertTokenizer.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2', do_lower_case=True)
transformer = transformers.AlbertModel.from_pretrained("albert-base-v2")
```

I tried:

```
transformer.num_parameters
```

But, It gives all layers with parameters :

> ```
> <bound method ModuleUtilsMixin.num_parameters of AlbertModel(
>   (embeddings): AlbertEmbeddings(
>     (word_embeddings): Embedding(30000, 128, padding_idx=0)
>     (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 128)
>     (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 128)
>     (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((128,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
>     (dropout): Dropout(p=0, inplace=False)
>   )
>   (encoder): AlbertTransformer(
>     (embedding_hidden_mapping_in): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=768, bias=True)
>     (albert_layer_groups): ModuleList(
>       (0): AlbertLayerGroup(
>         (albert_layers): ModuleList(
>           (0): AlbertLayer(
>             (full_layer_layer_norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
>             (attention): AlbertAttention(
>               (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
>               (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
>               (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
>               (attention_dropout): Dropout(p=0, inplace=False)
>               (output_dropout): Dropout(p=0, inplace=False)
>               (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
>               (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
>             )
>             (ffn): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
>             (ffn_output): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
>             (dropout): Dropout(p=0, inplace=False)
>           )
>         )
>       )
>     )
>   )
>   (pooler): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
>   (pooler_activation): Tanh()
> )>
> ```

I need to access to out_features = 768 the input of the last Linear function

> ((pooler): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True) )

Comment: What exactly do you need, the parameters of the layer or the input to the layer?

Comment: I need the out_features number "768".

Comment: Ok, then you can get it easily by typing - ```transformer.pooler.weight.shape[0]```

Comment: Thank you very much.
What about below code:

`import transformers`

`from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel`

`tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("nghuyong/ernie-tiny")`

`transformer = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("nghuyong/ernie-tiny")`

I want the number of output value in last layer = 50006.

Comment: `transformer.cls.predictions.decoder.out_features`

Comment: Do you need the model learned parameters at each layer? Check out the `save_features` function here: https://github.com/giganticode/probes/blob/main/probe_extractor.py)